# On the Markov property of a limit process

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

Let $E$ be a locally compact separable metric with countable base. We consider a sequence of Hunt processes $\{X^{(n)}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ on $E$. That is, each $X^{(n)}=(\{X_t^{(n)}\}_{t \in [0,\infty]},\{P_x^{(n)}\}_{x \in E})$ is a cad-lag Markov process on $E$ with the strong Markov property (and the quasi-left-continuity). Let $m$ be a probability measure on $E$. For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we write $P_{m}^{(n)}$ for the law of $X^{(n)}$ with initial distribution $m$.

We now assume the following condition.

${\rm \bf(A)}$ The laws $\{P_{m}^{(n)}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of $\{X^{(n)}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are tight in $D([0,\infty),E)$. Here,  $D([0,\infty),E)$ is the space of $E$-valued right continuous functions on $[0,\infty)$ with finite left limits.

Under the condition ${\rm \bf(A)}$, we have a subsequential limit $(X,P)$ of  $\{X^{(n)},P_m^{(n)}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}})$. For a bounded measurable function $f\colon E \to \mathbb{R}$, we set $(P_t f)(x)=E[f(X_t) \mid X_0=x]$ for $m$-a.e. $x$. Then, each $P_t$ is extended to a contraction operator on $L^\infty(E,m)$ (the extended operator is  denoted by the same symbol).

Can we show that $P_t(P_sf)=P_{t+s}f$ for every  $t,s>0$ and $f \in L^\infty(E,m)$?

That is, I would like to know that $(X,P)$ is a time-homogeneous Markov process on $E.$

Comment: Haven't gone through the details, but what if we work on $E = \mathbb{R}$, and define $X^{(n)}$ with the following transitions: from $0$ it jumps to either $1/n$ or $-1$ at rate 1.  The states $1/n$ and $1$ are absorbing.   It seems that in the limit, the state $1/n$ merges with $0$, so the process has probability $1/2$ to stay at 0 forever, which is impossible for a Markov process.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you for your comment. The state $0$ is a cemetery point for your limit process? If so, I feel that it does not necessarily contradict the Markov property. Am I making a mistake?

Comment: Maybe I have to think some more.  I guess the problem is that "initial state" becomes inconsistent in the limit.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you very much. If you know sufficient conditions to reach an affirmative conclusion, please let me know.

Comment: I think this is often studied in terms of convergence of the associated Dirichlet forms.  I don't know the exact results, but "Mosco convergence" comes up a lot.  https://doi.org/10.1006/jfan.1994.1093 seems to be the original paper

Comment: @NateEldredge I know this paper, but here the case where the Markov processes are symmetric is mainly studied. I am interested in more general situations.

Answer (score 0):

If your semigroups $\{P_t^{(n)}\}$ and $\{P_t\}$ are Feller then [Ethier and Kurtz](https://doi.org/10.1002/9780470316658) Theorem 4.2.5 give that your limiting process $X$ exists and is a Markov process (indeed, a Feller process).

This may seem obvious (since clearly $X$ is Markov if its semigroup is Feller) but without the Feller property, it's not always clear that $X$ exists. Ethier and Kurtz Corollary 4.2.8 gives an *if and only if* guarantee: if your semigroup $\{P_t\}$ is strongly continuous (and it is already a positive contraction semigroup) then in order for $X$ to exist, $\{P_t\}$ must also have a conservative generator, and thus be Feller.

In light of that, you might want to know when a convergent sequence of Feller semigroups has a limit that is also Feller. I'm afraid I don't know the answer to that. But there are at least several ways to check, see Theorem 6.3 in [Swart and Winter's lecture notes](https://www.uni-due.de/%7Ehm0112/teaching/markovprocesses-19ss/sw20.pdf). Chapter 6 of those notes also contains a more readable treatment of Ethier and Kurtz's convergence theorems (see in particular Corollary 6.11).